# postgres: find nested json value that matches value in array

Tags: json, postgresql

I have a product table, where `data` is a jsonb field.
The JSON inside looks like this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Paper",
  locations: [
     {locationId: 111, x: 1, y:1},
     {locationId: 210, x: 27, y:86},
     {locationId: 140, x: 34, y:134},
  ]
}
```

I have a query that returns the product where at least one location id matches a given id.

```
SELECT id FROM product WHERE product.data ->'locations' @> '[{"locationId: GIVEN_ID}]'
```

Now here's the question:I want to adapt the query for a GIVEN_ID_LIST to that I get all product where at least one locationId is in GIVEN_ID_LIST.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[step-by-step demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=2d2f17e03b3654f5d6eb84acf228e90d)

```
   SELECT DISTINCT                                                   -- 4
        mycol ->> 'name'                                             -- 3
    FROM
        mytable,
        json_array_elements(mycol -> 'locations') as elements        -- 1
    WHERE '[111, 210]'::jsonb @> (elements -> 'locationId')::jsonb   -- 2
```

1. Extract the array elements
2. Check if array element is part of your list (which is converted to type `jsonb` for being able to apply the `@>` operator)
3. Get product name
4. Because you could match several ids in one product, you have to eliminate these duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

For an OR condition, you need to unnest the array and combine that with an EXISTS condition

```
select p.id
from product p
where exists (select *
              from jsonb_array_elements(p.data -> 'locations') as x(item)
              where x.item ->> 'locationId' in ('1', '2', '3'));
```